# Azure Alert Rules enable/disable via Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts

I was asked to do a POC test that needs to toggle Azure Alert Rules to either enable or disable the alerts via the logic app.

So far I can get the logic app to display the json file of the "Microsoft. Insights/ActivityLogAlerts" that I have. Now I need help to figure out how I can enable/disable the alerts.

You can check the images for reference on my current setup.

[image]

[image]

PS. We can't use the alert processing rule since we don't want any alerts to appear on the alert dashboard because of monthly reporting purposes.

I tried doing the HTML request POST but I can't change the status of **"enabled": false,** to **"enabled": true,**

```
}
    "enabled": false,
    "description": "## THIS IS A TEST ALERT ##"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When updating an Activity log alert, you need to make a `PATCH` or `PUT` request to `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/{activityLogAlertName}?api-version=2020-10-01`  depending on what you want to update.

To simply disabled / enable the activity alert, use the `PATCH` request

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/187f412d-1758-44d9-b052-169e2564721d/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/SampleActivityLogAlertRule?api-version=2020-10-01

{
  "properties": {
    "enabled": false
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activity-log-alerts/update?tabs=HTTP

Alternatively use the `PUT` request to update the descriptions and properties.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/187f412d-1758-44d9-b052-169e2564721d/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/SampleActivityLogAlertRule?api-version=2020-10-01

{
    "enabled": true,
    "description": "Description of sample Activity Log Alert rule."
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activity-log-alerts/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP

I hope this helps

Alistair